# Is it necessary to create a different values folder for every different dimens screen density?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to have different dimens files according to each different screen density. I have done this by making the following procedure for each different screen size, but I have not created any new folder:
1- right-click on values folder
2- New-> Values Resource File
3- File name: dimens
4- Choose density qualifier
5- Choose the density that I want the dimens file to be attached to (example: X-High Density(xhdpi))
6- Click OK

So making this, I have in the values folder a dimens folder with all the different densities (but not a different folder for different densities, all the different densities files are in the same folder):

values/dimens/dimens(xxhdpi)

values/dimens/dimens(xhdpi)

values/dimens/dimens(hdpi)

values/dimens/dimens(ldpi)

...

It is working as expected, but I have seen many people that to do this they cereate a different values folder for each different density. So I am confused if what I have done is okay or I have to create a differnt values folder for each different screen density...

Image to let you understand what I have done:

I have in values folder the following:
[image]

Comment: Having values that vary by density is unusual. Dimensions usually are specified in density-independent units, such as `dp` or `sp`. Other types of values, such as strings, rarely vary based on density. Only create a `res/values...` directory for a density if you are going to put density-specific resources in there, and then only if you know *why* you are putting density-specific resources in there.

Comment: I have not undestood you really well, in the values older I have like 7 files, so is it necessary for me to create a different values folder for each different screen density? So will I have to copy paste all of those 7 files in new 5 folders for each screen density?

Comment: "so is it necessary for me to create a different values folder for each different screen density?" -- most likely no.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited the question to let you see an image of what I have, is it okay like and will work as expected?

Comment: I would remove the bottom three directories. You should only need one `dimens.xml` file, in `res/values/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare but I want to have different dimens values for those screen densities, do I have implemented it wrongly?

Comment: "but I want to have different dimens values for those screen densities" -- that is **very unusual**, and so you need a very good reason for doing that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to have different values according to the screen size for Top and Bottom margin in an element of my ConstraintLayout. I told you the example with screen density but actually I am making it with different screen size. Please, check the new update (now I have posted exactly what I am using)